# JUnit testing for Strings

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, junit, assert

I'm writing these methods for the class of StringUtility, but I get really stuck at writing some JUnit test for them.
The first method is reverse():

```
/**
 * @author Nguyen Vo
 */
public class StringUtility {
    public static String reverse(String sentence){
        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
        String[] sentenceArray = sentence.split("\\s+");
        String reversedSentence = "";
        
        for (int i = sentenceArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
            reversedSentence += sentenceArray[i] + " ";
        }
        return reversedSentence;
    }
```

The second one is maxOccuringCharacter(), which returns the max occuring char from a string:

```
    public static char maxOccuringCharacter(String sentence) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        
        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
        if (sentence == null || sentence.length() == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        char max_occuring_char = ' ';
        int max_count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(sentence.charAt(i))) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++) {
                    if (sentence.charAt(i) == sentence.charAt(j))
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > max_count) {
                    max_occuring_char = sentence.charAt(i);
                    max_count = count;
                }
            }
        }
        return max_occuring_char;
    }
```

And the last one is isPalindrome(). A palindrome is a sequence of characters that read the same backward as forward, such as madam or racecar.

```
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String sentence){
        
        if (sentence.equals("")){
            return true;
        }
        
        String anotherSentence = "";
        for (int i = sentence.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            anotherSentence += sentence.charAt(i);
        }
        
        return sentence.equals(anotherSentence);       
    }
}
```

Those code's syntax from StringUtility  is correct, but I get some trouble writing these JUnit testing: testReverse(), testMaxOccuringCharacterException(), textMaxOccuringCharacter(), and testIsPalindrome(). These at least looks good to me, but it keeps showing errors. Probably I got wrong somewhere somehow. Could anyone please give me a hand ?
Thanks for all your helps here!

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StringUtilityTester{
    private StringUtility a;

/**
 * Nguyen Vo
 */
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        a = new StringUtility();
    }

    @Test
    public void testReverse(){
        String reversedString = a.reverse("abc");
        assertEquals("cba", reversedString);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testMaxOccuringCharacter(){
        assertEquals('a', a.maxOccuringCharacter("aaaaaab"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsPalindrome(){
        assertEquals("madam", a.isPalindrome());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put the errors you got in the question, that would help people to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`isPalindrome(String)` accepts a string parameter, but you call it without param - `assertEquals("madam", a.isPalindrome());`

Another thing - you don't use static methods from instance, you use them from class itself. You should remove `a = new StringUtility();` and

```
String reversedString = a.reverse("abc");
```

should become

```
String reversedString = StringUtility.reverse("abc");
```

The same applies for the rest of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything about `testMaxOccuringCharacterException()` because you didn't share that test.

The `testIsPalindrome()` doesn't compile because it is missing a parameter to the `StringUtility.isPalindrome()` method: which string should be checked whether it is a palindrome or not?

To make the test class compile you need to change the `testIsPalindrome()` method into

```
@Test
public void testIsPalindrome() {
    assertEquals("madam", StringUtility.isPalindrome("madam"));
}
```

Please note that this change will make your test class compile but the `testIsPalindrome()` test will fail. This is because the `isPalindrome()` method returns a boolean (either true or false), but your test expects the returned value to be a string.

---

The `testReverse()` test fails because what the test verifies is not what the `reverse()` method does:

- The `reverse()` methods splits the input sentence into space separeted chunks (words) and reverses the sequence of those chunks (words) (i.e. it changes "hello world" into "world hello").
- The `testReverse()` tries to verify that "abc" is changed to "cba".